# Private WPF dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

In my WPF project I need to animate several properties with the same value. So my idea was to create a custom, private dependency property to which the animation will be applied. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. `DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty()` always returns `null` for this property. Here is the code:

```
public partial class PedestrianVisual : UserControl {
  private static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentInaccuracyRadiusProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentInaccuracyRadius", typeof(double), typeof(PedestrianVisual));
  private double CurrentInaccuracyRadius {
    get { return (double)GetValue(CurrentInaccuracyRadiusProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CurrentInaccuracyRadiusProperty, value); }
  }

  public PedestrianVisual() {
    InitializeComponent();

    // This returns "null" all the time.
    DependencyPropertyDescriptor dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(
      CurrentInaccuracyRadiusProperty, typeof(PedestrianVisual));
    dpd.AddValueChanged(this, (s, e) => { 
      UpdateInaccuracyCircle((double)GetValue(CurrentInaccuracyRadiusProperty)); 
    });
  }

  private void UpdateInaccuracyCircle(double curRadius) {
    // do something here
  }
}
```

Is there any other way to create a private dependency property?

Comment: Does it work when you make `CurrentInaccuracyRadiusProperty` public?

Comment: Just because DependencyPropertyDescriptor relies on the d-prop being public doesn't imply the d-prop itself doesn't work. If all you want to do is detect when the value changes, just specify a handler in the metadata for your d-prop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you would do it that way, i did not encounter any problems when attaching the callback in the declaration, e.g. something like this:

```
private static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentInaccuracyRadiusProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register
    (
        "CurrentInaccuracyRadius",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(PedestrianVisual),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0, (s, e) =>
        {
            UpdateInaccuracyCircle((PedestrianVisual)s, (double)e.NewValue);
        })
    );
```

(*`UpdateInaccuracyCircle` method should be static in this case*)

If you want to stick with the instance method:

```
private static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentInaccuracyRadiusProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register
    (
        "CurrentInaccuracyRadius",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(PedestrianVisual),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0, (s, e) =>
        {
            ((PedestrianVisual)s).UpdateInaccuracyCircle((double)e.NewValue);
        })
    );
```

Comment: Or a more standard approach is to have the callback (OnCurrentInaccuracyRadius) static, and then cast the DependencyObject parameter ("s" in H.B's example) to the required type (PedestrianVisual) and call a non-static callback (again, called OnCurrentInaccuracyRadius) passing old value and new value as parameters. Inside that callback, you can call UpdateInaccuracyCircle. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

To further update H.B's answer, the standard approach is along these lines:

```
static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentInaccuracyRadiusProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register
(
    "CurrentInaccuracyRadius",
    typeof(double),
    typeof(PedestrianVisual),
    new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0, OnCurrentInaccuracyRadiusChanged)
);

static void OnCurrentInaccuracyRadiusChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var pedVisual = d as PedestrianVisual;
    if (pedVisual != null)
        pedVisual.OnCurrentInaccuracyRadiusChanged((double)e.OldValue, (double)e.NewValue);
}

void OnCurrentInaccuracyRadiusChanged(double oldValue, double newValue)
{
    UpdateInaccuracyCircle(newValue);
}
```